# Forge file conversion for Viewer -- translation stuck at x%

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

Using a Revit 2016 model with three 3D views flagged for conversion using the "Collaboration" ribbon add-in, the conversion process reports "inprogress" and halts at x% (54% in this specific case).  It has been over 24 hours and the progress hasn't changed.  Removing one of the larger 3D views in the model and uploading to a different bucket allows the conversion to complete.  I am able to reproduce this.

Is there some size or complexity limit that gets exceeded and causes the service to just give up?  Is there any more detailed information about the job that can be obtained through the API?

Comment: There is no theoretical size and complexity as far as I'm aware of. You can get some basic info if the job has failed or not by looking at the GET manifest response: https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-GET. But I suspect that's what you already did in order to get the progress %. That's about as much info as you can get at the moment.

Comment: So is the answer that the service will fail on some models and provide no additional information?  Does autodesk have any recommendation about how to avoid this situation?  We are going to ask clients to use this service and it's tough to say, "The model viewer service will randomly fail on some models but that's just how it works.  Try another model."  Is there another support channel I should be contacting?

Comment: If a model loads fine in Revit (not corrupted, or missing dependencies, ...) it should most likely work with our translation service, unfortunately there might be some isolated cases. You can log private requests and share links to dataset at forge.help@autodesk.com

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since we got your question. Actually in the same period, we got a couple of similar reports. I am sharing some info from my side:

With these reports, two scenarios:

1. some customers used v1 process to translate, it might probably something special with v1 with special model, so the translation was stuck. While v1 will be retired soon, the suggestion is to migrate to v2
   https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/end-life-notice-view-and-data-api
2. Some customers are using v2 but also hit similar issue,  this is specific to models. The workaround is [publish views] , select some views in Revit and save this model. translate again and the process can succeed.

Hope this helps.